# Лицензия GNU GPL v3 вместе с MIT

Tags: лицензирование

Есть проект написанный под лицензией *GNU General Public License v3.0* и я хочу использовать в этом проекте какие-либо библиотеки, например - реакт с MIT лицензией.

Я могу это сделать? И нужно ли описывать все подключенные MIT библиотеки в каком либо файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать можно.

При распространение кода/бинарников отдельно от библиотек под MIT, указывать ничего не обязательно.

При совместном распространении нужно таскать копию MIT-лицензии с копирайтом (указанием авторства) и указанием какие именно части подпадают под оную.

*Дисклеймер*: я не юрист и оставляю за собой право заблуждаться и непреднамеренно вводить других в заблуждение по юридическим вопросам... ;)